# Office 365 New Library Experience and Metadata Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, metadata-navigation

Is anyone aware of a way to use the 'New experience' type layout for a document library in Sharepoint Online in addition to the Key Filters box exposed by Metadata Based Nav?

I have enabled Metadata Nav and assigned fields as key filters, but they only show when using the Classic experience (under Advanced settings for the library) - if using the New experience, the left hand pane just has the quick launch links, and no key filters. Can't see them anywhere else either.

Does this seem to be a by-design thing, or am I missing something?

Comment: It's not only metadata navigation that it affects. Also for us the left and top navigation are all wrong though we don't use metadata navigation. This is valid in the publishing sites. On team sites the navigation is ok with the new experience.

Comment: I agree with Haapo, new library experience is completely BROKE with publshing on even with structured nav. The new experience displays ALL sites and ALL pages in top and left navigation. I have unticked the show pages / sites in navigation to ZERO effect. Total disaster !!!!!

Comment: For those disappointed to see tree view left behind, you could vote to bring it back here: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/19270162-bring-back-tree-interface-for-managed-metadata-nav

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed metadata navigation is only available in the classic mode experience. If that is necessary, revert your library in the Advanced Settings to classic mode.

Features available only in classic mode

The Ribbon

- The Ribbon itself
- Certain features available through the Ribbon:

  - Popularity trends
  - Tags & Notes
  - Quick Edit
  - RSS Feed
  - Most Popular Items
  - Connect to Outlook
  - Connect to Office
  - Export to Excel
  - Form Web Parts
  - Edit Library
  - New Quick Step

View features

- Item totals
- Custom styles (such as Basic Table or Document Details)

Navigation features

- Tree view
- Metadata navigation and filtering
- Managed navigation
- Per-location views
- Customized navigation links on publishing sites

Library features

- External data columns
- Geolocation columns
- Content organizer
- Follow feature

Customizations

- Minimal Download Strategy (MDS)
- SharePoint Server Publishing
- JSLink code on fields or views
- CustomActions that include ScriptBlock or ScriptSrc properties
  CustomActions that do not include ScriptBlock or ScriptSrc properties will continue to work as expected

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-the-new-document-library-experience-and-classic-mode-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US